# Constructor that handles exception

Tags: java, android

How can i make constructor that can handle IOException

this is the class with constructor

```
public class RootProcess {
Process process;

public RootProcess() throws IOException {

}

public RootProcess(Process process){
    this.process = process;
}

public Process getProcess() {
    return process;
}

public void setProcess(Process process) {
    this.process = process;
}


}
```

And this is how i declare it

```
RootProcess process = new RootProcess(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"));
```

but i get this error in eclipse

```
Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute the superuser command on an Android phone? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you running this from a method either declare the exception in method signature or handle it using try/catch block.

**Declaring the exception:**

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException {
     RootProcess process = new RootProcess(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"));
}
```

**Handle the Exception:**

```
public void someMethod() {
try {
RootProcess process = new RootProcess(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"));
}
catch(IOException ex){
//handle it here
}
}
```

Comment: @pedja no worries, it does happen some times.. you are welcome :)